# How to change the threshold of a prediction of multi-label classification using FASTAI library

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I have a multi-label dataset that I'm using to train my model using fast-ai library for Python, using as metrics an accuracy function such as:

```
def accuracy_multi1(inp, targ, thresh=0.5, sigmoid=True):
    "Compute accuracy when 'inp' and 'targ' are the same size"
    if sigmoid: inp=inp.sigmoid()
    return ((inp>thresh) == targ.bool()).float().mean()
```

And my learner is like:

```
learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet50, metrics=partial(accuracy_multi1,thresh=0.1))
learn.fine_tune(2,base_lr=3e-2,freeze_epochs=2)
```

After training my model, I want to predict an image considering the threshold I used a argument, but the method `learn.predict('img.jpg')` only considers the default `thres=0.5`. In the following example, my predidction should return `True` for  'red, 'shirt' and 'shoes', as their probabilities are above 0.1 (but shoes is below 0.5, so it is not considered as True):

```
def printclasses(prediction,classes):
    print('Prediction:',prediction[0])
    for i in range(len(classes)):
        print(classes[i],':',bool(prediction[1][i]),'|',float(prediction[2][i]))

printclasses(learn.predict('rose.jpg'),dls.vocab)
```

Output:

```
Prediction: ['red', 'shirt']
black : False | 0.007274294272065163
blue : False | 0.0019288889598101377
brown : False | 0.005750810727477074
dress : False | 0.0028723080176860094
green : False | 0.005523672327399254
hoodie : False | 0.1325301229953766
pants : False | 0.009496113285422325
pink : False | 0.0037188702262938023
red : True | 0.9839697480201721
shirt : True | 0.5762518644332886
shoes : False | 0.2752271890640259
shorts : False | 0.0020902694668620825
silver : False | 0.0009014935349114239
skirt : False | 0.0030087409541010857
suit : False | 0.0006510693347081542
white : False | 0.001247694599442184
yellow : False | 0.0015280473744496703
```

Is there a way to impose the threshold when I'm doing a prediction of a image I'm referencing? Something that would look like:

```
learn.predict('img.jpg',thresh=0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem. I remain interested in a better solution, but since `accuracy_mult` only seems to provide user-friendly evaluation of the model during the training process (and is not involved in the prediction), I created a work-around for my data.

The basic idea is to take the tensor with the actual predictions (which is the third entry in the 3-tuple returned by the `predict()` function), apply the threshold & get the corresponding labels from the vocab.

```py
def predict_labels(x, model, thresh=0.5):
  '''
  function to predict multi-labels in text (x)

  arguments:
  ----------
  x: the text to predict
  model: the trained learner
  thresh: thresh to indicate which labels should be included, fastai default is 0.5

  return:
  -------
  (str) predictions separated by blankspace
  '''

  # getting categories according to threshold
  preds = model.predict(x)[2] > thresh
  labels = model.dls.multi_categorize.vocab[preds]

  return ' '.join(labels)
```

Comment: That's exactly the workaround I was using so far until I don't get a definitive solution!